# TextField doesn't work correctly with InputProps "max" attribute when the input is manually typed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to render MUI TextField with code below:

```
<TextField
  variant="standard"
  type="number"
  InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0, max: 5 } }}
  onChange={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // some_code...
  }}
/>
```

However it seems like it doesn't work with manually typed input. When using the UP/DOWN arrows it doesn't allow for the value to go above 5- as expected. Should I handle it in onChange event because that's expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to limit the input value is by managing `onChange`.
Also you need a state for saving the input value.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");

return (
  <TextField
    variant="standard"
    type="number"
    value={value}
    onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const newValue = Number(event.target.value);
      if (newValue >= 0 && newValue <= 5) setValue(newValue.toString());
    }}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

is not InputProps is inputProps...

please check code below

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-lehmann-lo3vkd?file=/src/App.js:0-263

```
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  const inputProps = {
    min: 0,
    max: 5
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField type="number" inputProps={inputProps} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The minlength/maxlength props are valid with type="text" TextField only. I'm using type="number" and it's inputProps are min/max.

Comment: @Jorhanc I updated the response and the link please check it again